# How do I get an Environment Variable in C# that was set in GitHub Codespaces?

Tags: c#, .net-core, github-codespaces

I am using .NET Core 7.

I have set an environment variable in Github Codespaces using the settings secret:
https://github.com/settings/codespaces

When I try to get it out using C# it is blank because code spaces is not using windows:

```
string result = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GOLD");
```

How do I get the secret in C#?

Comment: *"it is blank because code spaces is not using windows"* - that's a pretty big leap in attribution of causality. Of all the computing concepts, environment variables are one of the most uniform across platforms. If Codespaces is *actually* setting an environment variable, that code will work. Maybe the repository wasn't granted access?

Comment: The repository was granted access prior to trying the code above.